# Telethon/Python change client inside a loop cycle

Tags: python, asynchronous, client, telegram, telethon

I'm new with Python and I have this problem:

I'm building a client with Telethon and i need to switch the client account in a cycle.
I think it is necessary to illustrate the structure of import of my code and say that i haven't used "async" and "await" at all in my code, because I'm still learning and because I'm facing this problem for the first time.

The main file is named `setup.py`, which have an import of `menu.py`

menu.py have an import of `adding.py`

adding.py have an import of `voip.py`

voip.py have this function, which test the connection to a Telegram account:

```
def test_connection(telefono,apiID,hashID,silent_mode):
    try:
        client = TelegramClient(telefono, apiID, hashID)

    except ApiIdInvalidError:
        client = False
    except Exception as e:
        client = False

    try:
        client.connect()
        if not client.is_user_authorized():
            client.send_code_request(telefono)    
            client.sign_in(telefono, input(colors.cy+'[+] Inserisci il codice ricevuto su Telegram --> '+colors.re))
        else:
            if silent_mode == False:
                print(colors.cy+"[-] Accesso eseguito correttamente")
    
    except ApiIdInvalidError:
        client = False
    except Exception as e:
        client = False

    return client
```

This function is called in adding.py, inside a function loop where at every cycle the parameters for TelegrmClient() change.
Everything is working fine with with the first account, but not with the second one, **it does not give error on the connection by the way after the second cycle of the loop**. But if I try to add a user to a group with this new client variable (`client = test_connection(params...)` it is not working )

I've tried using an array intead of a variable client, but Telethon say that this method of reference is not usable.
And i've tried with async and await before every functions, but this is not working too

Comment: Beware that attempting to abuse Telegram's API (for example, by mass-registering phone numbers) is prone to lead to account bans (and in particular, VoIP numbers aren't well-received).